# C++ std::bad_alloc error when using smaller amount of memory?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, memory, while-loop

I made a function which is able to store all the solutions to secret number which are then to be used in the algorithm.

This function works great for certain input values; however, for some it does not work. The issue is that I am getting an error which is related to using too much memory which does not make sense considering:

The limit to how many numbers are generated is:

```
int possibilities = std::pow(symbols, length);
```

when you do:

```
generate_list( list , 6, 4 ); it generates 4^6 different numbers = 4096
```

However when you do:

```
 generate_list( list , 4, 6 ); it does not generates 6^4 numbers = 1296 due to error
```

How is it giving a not enough memory error when it generates less numbers?

The error is:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
     what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Comment: Big rule of debugging: don't assume. The limit to how many numbers are generated is (number of symbols)^length **only if the code behaves as intended**. Since the code is not behaving as intended, that limit is out the window. Do some debugging to confirm the sizes of your vectors. Perhaps output the length every time you call `push_back`.

Comment: The code is critical to answering your question, and needs to stay as part of the question.

Comment: Please don't delete the code. As @1201ProgramAlarm said, the answer doesn't make sense without it.

Comment: This code Is currently in use for an assignment I will re upload it when its over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not have anything to do with memory allocation per se.

The problem is in these line

```
        int zerosneeded = length - tmp.size();

        while (zerosneeded != 0) {
            tmp.push_back(0);
            zerosneeded--;
        }
```

without knowing why it does what it does, the question I have when looking at the code is "can `zerosneeded` be less than zero?". Especially since `zerosneeded` is defined as `int` instead of `unsigned int` (applicable to the rest of the code).

If zerosneeded is less than zero, there will be an infinite loop allocating until exhaustion. A quick check confirms this:

```
int zerosneeded = length - tmp.size();
if(zerosneeded < 0)
{
    std::cout << "fatal, zerosneeded < 0 \n";
    throw std::runtime_exception("fatal, zerosneeded < 0");
}
```

I hope this helps in your debugging.

**Edit**

As to why is zerosneeded is negative:

firstly, the number of possibilities are calculated, which is symbols^length.

```
int possibilities = std::pow(symbols, length);
```

when pushing values to tmp, we basically find first x such that length^x > quotient. The quotient is in the range [0,symbols^length] and is used push values into tmp.

```
int quotient = i;
while (quotient!=0) {
    tmp.push_back(quotient % length);
    quotient = quotient / length;
}
```

If symbols^length > length^length, first x such that length^x > quotient yields x > length, making `int zerosneeded = length - tmp.size();` get negative.

For the example we have length = 4, symbols = 6, so quotients have a range of [0,6^4] = [0, 1296]. But already for 256 we have 4^4 = 256 => 4^5 > 256, so our x = 5 => zerosneeded = 4 - 5 = -1.

This is nothing special for length = 4 and symbols = 6, and should actually occur as long as length < symbols.